# Philodendron McColley’s Finale older leaves turning brown

Tags: houseplants

My Philodendron McColley’s Finale’s old leaves have been getting brown that spreads across the whole leaf eventually.  I’ve had about 3 that have fallen off.  At first I thought they were just getting old, but this doesn’t look normal.  Also, there are new red leaves but they haven’t opened up.  Does anyone know what is causing this brown?  Of the 4 big leaves, 2 on one side have this browning and the other two so far seem okay.  The New ones in the middle aren’t opening up

[image]

Comment: Can you share more about feeding, watering, distance from the window, and humidity levels?

Comment: I’ve been watering it maybe once a week, though there was one week I might have not watered it for 2 weeks.  I live in a narrow north facing apartment, so there isn’t much direct light.  It is in the middle of the place where it gets solid indirect light but isn’t very close to the window. 

I do have a misting diffuser maybe 1.5 feet away from it (I live in an area that isn’t dry).  I don’t notice it having an effect on the plant, as I have tried rotating it when I see the brown emerging. The brown areas aren’t dry.  They are moist like the rest of the leaf but just gradually spreading.